# How do I get the meter reading from a tethered Canon DSLR programmatically?

Tags: canon, eos-utility, programming

I'm quite an amateur in photography and have to take several photos from similar objects in the same place during the day. So, I use Canon utilities' software libraries to write a C# program, and do this with my computer.

I have a Canon EOS 1100D and know how to set the properties in camera manual mode with my computer, but I want to adjust all metering parameters that would change in different light situations in my program dynamically.

How can I get and set all the metering parameters? I can set ISO and focus in Auto mode, but I need all the camera metering parameters.

Comment: Sorry, but you have to elaborate on what you want to accomplish here. Do you want to use auto or manual mode? In auto you have almost zero control of the settings, tethered or not.

Comment: I use tethering mode and control the camera with my program(computer); so, have to set the camera on *manual* mode. But I need to get meterig prarameters from the camera.

Comment: There are several ways to approach the problem of changing light levels. Which way would work best depends on how much difference there is between the brightest and dimmest light at times you want the program to take a photo.

Comment: As I said, I have to take photos during the day; and I have problem with all of the photos that had been taken at sunset. they are too bright. when I manualy set the Tv from 1/15 into 1/40, the problem will be solved. But I want the program take this decision as the same manner of camera when is on *Auto* mode. I want to do this with teathering.

Comment: Even though I still think that programming questions should go to the [SO] page. Here is a library i found that have the functions you may be looking for. [gPhoto](http://www.gphoto.org/doc/remote/). I didn't post this as an answer is because I don't have a Canon Camera, and not familiar with the Library.

Comment: It is still really unclear what you are asking.  I'm both a photographer and a developer, but I have no idea what you are trying to accomplish here.  You say you know how to adjust properties in manual mode but then say you want to know how to adjust parameters.  Then you talk about what you can change in auto.  What are you actually trying to accomplish and what specific parameters do you need to adjust?

Comment: @AJHenderson: first of all, thanks a lot. When I said I know how to adjust properties in manual mode, I mean I know how should set for example Tv on 1/15 or ISO on 100. But what I don't know is how I can found the best value of these parameters for each photo. this is exactly the camera's work when it's on *Auto* mode: product the best value and set them, the take then photo.

Comment: Ahhh. So you don't want to _adjust_ the metering, you want to _read_ it, and then manually set the exposure parameters (shutter speed, aperture, ISO) once you know that.

Comment: That said, in my opinion, that puts this squarely [off-topic](http://photo.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) as a programming question.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about programming rather than photography.

Comment: @aisa: Make your question more photography-related, and people will stop telling you this question is off-topic (which it is as-is). :-) However, an interesting question would be: if you cannot get the camera into auto, how would you calculate the parameters from a test shoot - which is an approach BTW. Capture a test picture, calculate lightness/contrast/color balance, whatever, and make adjustments manually (programmatically). After all, "auto" does the same, except it has a database to figure out what are you taking picture of and creates a strategy.

Comment: @mattdm: I asked my questions in StackOverFlow too, but apparently nobody knows anything about my problem. No comment, no answer.

Comment: Does your program _only_ work with the camera in "M" mode? As an example, when you're taking the sunset photo's, set the camera to Tv mode, rather than "M" (if it's suited in your code). Otherwise, if it has to be in "M" mode, the camera won't metre.

Comment: Unfortunately it has to be on Manual mode. Is there any way to call camera metering function manually(by code) and force camera to metering and then get the parameters?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have access to Canon's SDK to know what's possible or not, but thought I'd point out you can also use [libgphoto](http://www.gphoto.org/proj/libgphoto2/) to interact with a tethered camera. It allows you to read and write a variety of camera settings. On the 1100D [this includes](http://www.gphoto.org/doc/remote/) ISO, aperture and shutter speed (and much more) so should be enough.

You can even script this using Gphoto2 (which obviously runs on libgphoto), a command-line utility that lets you get/set basic info like this, without having to call C code directly from the library.

Most likely this will *not* work at the same time as the EOS Utility or in parallel with Canon's software library, so it's one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is programming-related, so I can only provide one link for you if you cannot find out any other ways. (And this answer is photography related BTW, unlike my comment).

There is a hack called [CHDK](http://chdk.wikia.com/wiki/CHDK) which allows much finer control over your camera, and most probably you can either tether out all the internal configuration and measurement values or you could ask those folks about this.

Have a look, maybe try that, and if you did so, please let us know if that worked out (I am an ex-Canon fan, currently on Nikons, but really miss CHDK :-) ).

EDIT: another way as a workaround: make a test photo, download it, and check out the EXIF data, there are many parameters saved there.

Answer (score 0):

API library does not give this info ? strange for an official API.

another way, if you cannot use a method from the API, is to take a picture and read the info from the EXIF. Picture could be take with the lower resolution/quality (for fast transfert/treatment )

Answer (score 0):

To add a little more details than the previous answers: on my Canon Rebel XSi, the photos I take have a `MeasuredEV` and `MeasuredEV2` tag in the EXIF data.  Unfortunately I haven't been able to find a way to get this information *before* taking a photo, but for my purposes (taking a time-lapse) using the measured value from the last photo taken is acceptable.

(I also don't know what the difference is between the two tags, other than one seems to give a more precise value while the other seems to be rounded off)